# Integrate OfferWall in Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, fyber

I'm searching to integrate the Fyber SDK into a xamarin.Forms cross-platform app to integrate an OfferWall. The problem is that I do not find any documentation by Xamarin side and by Fyber it only tells me the way is usually done (with Natives SDKs). I already looked for a Binding Library but Still learning how to use them.

¿Is there any other way? ¿Any tips?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best solution is to create a `Binding Library` with the OfferWall .jar library

There a link to explain you how to create a `Binding Library` for android: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

And this one for binding a .jar library: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-a-jar/

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this links, gonna search for the iOS solution also.

Comment: For iOS is almost the same process. You should create a `Binding Library` project and import an Objective-C or Swift library.

Comment: @Eastrall FYI: `Xamarin.iOS` binding projects currently only support ObjC libraries/frameworks. Also Swift does not create *libraries*, only frameworks